# Show that if a circle with centre $(a,b)$ passes through the two points of intersection, then $a=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For the equations $x^2+y^2=25$ and $x^2+(y-7)^2=18$ show that if a circle with centre $(a,b)$ passes through the two points of intersection, then $a=0$.

I have sketched these equations in Wolfram Alpha and I can see that any circle that passed through the two points of intersection would need to be symmetric about the x-axis. However I think I need more rigorous proof. I know that the equation of a circle centre $(a,b)$ can be written in the form $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2= R^2$ (where $R$ is the radius).

I have solved the two simultaneous equations and have found a circle with centre $(0,2)$ that passes through their points of intersection.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sketch of an argument. Fill in as much detail as you need.

The two points of intersection are of the form $(+x_0, y_0)$ and $(-x_0, y_0)$ with $x_0 \neq 0$. If those two points lie on another circle, $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = R^2$, then

$$(x_0 - a)^2 = R^2 - (y_0-b)^2 = (-x_0 - a)^2$$

It follows that $a = 0$.